# How youtube achieve opening app from Google or Youtube

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, youtube

When users enter my mobile website, I want to detect that a user installed my specific app or not, then If it installed, I want to redirect my user to my native app.

I tried below

**HTML**

```
<a class="intent" href="http://mymobilewebsite"  data-scheme="myApp://"></a>
```

**Javascript**

```
(function () {

            goToUri($("a.intent").data('scheme'), $("a.intent").attr('href'));
            event.preventDefault();

            function goToUri(uri, href) {
                var start, end, elapsed;

                start = new Date().getTime();
                document.location = uri;

                end = new Date().getTime();

                elapsed = (end - start);

                if (elapsed < 1) {
                    document.location = href;
                }
            }               
        })();
```

this does not work at all.

I searched how youtube does that because I know when I type youtube ton google and click youtube's mobile website link, android asking me to perform to complete that action on youtube app.

[image: Here Screen Shot from my mobile]

How youtube achieve that perform, could not find out ?

**Edit** : My Question pointed as duplicated, in my question, I am asking that I want to solve this problem only in mobile website

Comment: You can find the answer to your question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser).

Answer (score -1):

Use this in ur class

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.equals("YOURLINK")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), YourActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return false;
        }else{
            view.loadURL(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

You can start any kind of files i.e audio, video or image anything.

Comment: So you are saying that I can achieve  this from native app

Comment: The answer is wrong. It will not work from a browser. It will work only from a WebView inside the app.